# React Redux reducer is not getting triggered

Tags: reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux, reducers

I am not able to understand why reducer is being called in one case and not in another case. The footer component is given below.

File `Footer.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import './Footer.scss';
import * as footerActions from '../../redux/actions/footer';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state;//{state: state, footerState: getFooterData(state)};
};

// Footer component is aware of only footer actions
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(footerActions, dispatch)
  };
};

var Footer = React.createClass({
  propTypes:{
    state: React.PropTypes.object,
    actions: React.PropTypes.object
  },
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.actions.changeLanguage("dutch");//<-- This calls reducer and changes language
  },
  changeLang(language) {
    this.props.actions.changeLanguage("spanish");//<--- This doesn't calls reducer
  },
  render() {
    var that = this;
    return (
      <div className="footer">
        <div onClick={that.changeLang.bind(that, 'english')}>English</div>
        <div onClick={that.changeLang.bind(that,'german')}>German</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Footer);
```

actions file `footer`

```
export const LANGUAGE_CHANGE  = 'LANGUAGE_CHANGE';

export function changeLanguage(data, context) {
  return {
    type: LANGUAGE_CHANGE,
    data
  };
}
```

Reducer file `footer`

```
import { LANGUAGE_CHANGE } from '../actions/footer';

export default function footer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LANGUAGE_CHANGE:
      debugger;
      return  Object.assign({}, state, {language:action.data});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In `footer.jsx` component code, dispatching  `LANGUAGE_CHANGE` action from `componentDidMount` method successfully calls `footer` reducer but, reducer is not called when `LANGUAGE_CHANGE` action dispatched from `changeLang` method. Not able to figure out what is going wrong ? Help Appreciated.

Comment: Is there any javascripts errors? where debbuger get you when debugging inside `this.props.actions.changeLanguage`?

Comment: No javascript errors. It takes control                                                                             ```function bindActionCreator(actionCreator, dispatch) {
  return function () {
    return dispatch(actionCreator.apply(undefined, arguments));
  };
}```

Comment: Why are you using `bindActionCreators`? From the docs: "The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn’t aware of Redux". Your Footer component is already wrapped in connect so this is a little redundant.

Comment: @azium: using bindActionCreators with connect is the usual use case. I don't think there is anything wrong with this

Comment: @DamienLeroux it makes sense if you're passing down those actions to a child component that is not connected only.. http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html

Comment: @azium: I believe it make sense in this case, it avoids having to use dispatch inside component. As a result, if `this.props.actions.changeLanguage` has to be changed in a callback no linked to Redux, it doesn"t require any modification inside the component `Footer `.

Comment: Is `changeLang` method in the component executed? 
Did you have try to call `this.props.actions.changeLanguage()` directly from `onClick` event attribute? What's happen?  Ex. `<div onClick={this.props.actions.changeLanguage('german')}>German</div>`

Comment: @NickGnd I tried ```<div onClick={()=> this.props.actions.changeLanguage('german')}>German</div>```. What you mentioned will be in infinite loop, I think